# OpenCV - OpenCV Mat equivalent of boost matrix array_type

Tags: c++, opencv, boost, matrix

So I am trying to figure out what would be the equivalent of this:

```
boost::numeric::ublas::matrix<T>::array_type& matrix_data = prev_matrix.data();
```

but using the OpenCV Mat class?

I am trying to use cv::Mat to replace already existing code base which was originally using the boost matrix and this part has me somewhat perplexed.

I have the following:

```
cv::Mat& matrix_data(prev_matrix); <--prev_matrix is also a cv::Mat now

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < matrix_data.size(); ++i) <--- line that has an error
{
    matrix_data[i] = value;
}
```

but I get the following error:

```
error: no match for ‘operator<’ in ‘i < cv::Mat::MSize::operator()() const()’
```

I am trying to wrap my head around the two different objects but for some reason, even reading the documentation does not provide insight into how to correctly fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `matrix_data.size()` use `matrix_data.total()`. The `size()` function returns type `Size` whereas it appears you're just looking for the total number of elements as returned by `total()`.